# Calendarlist returns empty result set with service account

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client, service-accounts

I'm trying to get a connexion between a google Calendar account and the google calendar API to update a MySQL database based on the events contained by the google calendar. It seems that my client is set up, and now I have to get the CalendarList, but I'm having trouble here.

I took inspiration on what have been done in the quickstart.php and what is explained in the google documentation to try some tests.

> The problem is that all my requests return an empty result when I use the method getItems();

## My code:

```
function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Calendar API PHP synchroniser');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);
    $client->setAuthConfig('Path/To/My/AccountService/File.json');
    $client->setAccessType('online');
    $client->setPrompt('MyCalendarWithMyData');

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    /*
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            //I don't know what to put here.
        }
    }
    */
    return $client;
}

$client = getClient(); // based on quickstart.php

$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);// from the sample on documentation

$calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList();
$calendars=$calendarList->getItems();
var_dump($calendars);
```

My goal is when I got the calendar list to get each events relative to each calendar in the calendar list to update my database.
Thanks
G.G

Comment: Welcome to stack "its not working" is really hard for us to help with.  Please edit your question include your code and describe any issues you are having with your solution error messages for example.    you may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry but I made something wrong  while making my question now should be better

Comment: Sorry I still dont understand your question.  It looks like you are requesting data from the api are you not getting any data back?   The code you have posted has nothing to do with events or mysql.  you need to give us a https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex that we can use to see the issue.

Comment: Yes I want to get the calendarList of the account but when I try it, it returns no data. But, when I try directly on google CalendarList API with the function "Try it", it returns my expected data.  Did I do something wrong in the code above ?

Comment: Are you using a service account?  Are you logging in with the exact same user you are using in "Try it"?

Comment: I created a service account, I downloaded the json file and I put the path to it in the following method:
```PHP
$client->setAuthConfig('My/Path/To/My/AccountService/File.json');
```

Answer (score 3):

What you need to remember is that a Service account is not you.  A service account is a dummy user.  This user has its own google calendar account, drive account and probably a few more.

If you do a

```
$calendar = $service->calendars->get('primary');
echo $calendar->getSummary();
```

You will see that in fact your service account does have a calendar.  What it doesnt have is anything by default in its calendar list.

If you want it to have access to your personal Google calendar then you will need to go to the google calendar website and share the calendar with the service accounts email address. then it should be able to do the following make sure you note the calendar id for the calendar you shared with it while you are in the settings.

```
$calendar = $service->calendars->get('calendarid');

echo $calendar->getSummary();
```

If you really want it in calendar list you can add it.

```
$calendarListEntry = new Google_Service_Calendar_CalendarListEntry();
$calendarListEntry->setId("calendarId");

$createdCalendarListEntry = $service->calendarList->insert($calendarListEntry);

echo $createdCalendarListEntry->getSummary();
```

## Service account set up

As i have mentioned service accounts need to be preauthorized. You need to go to the Google Calendar website and under settings for the calendar you want it to be able to access you need to share the calendar with it as shown

[image]

## useful links

- [Oauth2 service accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)
- [Google developer console Service accounts](https://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-service-account/)

Comment: I tried what you've given with the get method, I got the main calendar I wanted. But in fact, this calendar is linked to several others calendars and it's that I want to get with the calendarList, because when I'll have those calendars, I'll need to extract each events of those to update my database.

Comment: Then you need to do an insert into calendar list if you really want it in there.  All calendar list is really is the list used to display on the bottom left hand side of the google calendar website.  As a service account has no ability to use the google calendar website it has by default nothing in its calendar list.    Calendars are not linked to each other.  There is something you are misunderstanding about google calendar

Comment: If you know the calendar you want events from why not just use a https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list?

Comment: Yes I don't understand, aswell you said before:
"Are you using a service account? Are you logging in with the exact same user you are using in "Try it"? "
It seems not because when I try to get events on the main calendar lot of the datas are protected and I cannot access it.
When I tried the "Try it" function on google calendar api's website I did just checked the OAuth2.0 and pressed "execute" How can I know what did google used to do this request ?

Comment: What client type did you create in Google developer console?  If you created an Oauth2 (Browser) client then when you ran your code it would pop up and ask you to login as a user and grant them access.   If you are using a service account then the server account is preauthorized with its own account its its own user.

Comment: I did create:
-1 API key
-1 OAuth 2.0 client IDs
-1 Service account keys

Comment: And which one are you using in your code?  why dont you edit your question  post your getClient method for me to see.   You probably only need one of those not all three.

Comment: Post edited, idk how to use the OAuth2.0 client ID, when I try it says me internal error 500. Then, I tried on service account and it seems to work but as said before not really, I'll go to watch what you said in your edited answer

Comment: I think you should take a step back and follow the tutorial and understand how it works that code isnt even remotely correct for Oauth2 or service accounts https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php

Comment: I used and tested this tutorial, my test code is based on it. I tried to modify it to adapt to my problems. The problem is that I don't really understand the part about the client initialization. :/     Then I tried to understand it on my own but as you have seen, that's not good.

Comment: try this https://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-oauth2/  then try this https://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-service-account/

Comment: It seems that I've found a way to find all my datas by using the service account, and doing this request ``` $service->events->listEvents($calendarId) ``` just in a loop and modifying the $calendarId each time I call it

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue and followed the following steps to resolve it.

Go to your calender setting and share your calender with the service account.
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/settings

[image]

Also, pls note down the calenderId from your account on the same page.
[image]

Once you are done doing this, it will start working. I am also pasting my python code snippet for the reference.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'personal-390418-9fb901964171.json'

creds = None
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)

start_date = datetime(2023, 6, 1).isoformat() + 'Z'  # 'Z' indicates UTC time
end_date = datetime(2023, 6, 22).replace(hour=23, minute=59, second=59).isoformat() + 'Z'

events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='$CALENDER_ID', timeMin=start_date,
                                      timeMax=end_date,
                                      singleEvents=True,
                                      orderBy='startTime').execute()

print(events_result)
events = events_result.get('items', [])

if not events:
    print('No events found for this day.')
else:
    print(f'Events for {start_date}:')
    for event in events:
        start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
        print(f'{start} - {event["summary"]}')
```

Just replace $CALENDER_ID in above code snippet and replace the variable SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE value with your service account JSON.